Is this the correct approach for writing TUP upgrade scripts using Foundry?
So I'm building LayerMarket and we're currently working on testnet beta testing, initial user acquisition, and gathering early adopter feedback.
From the feedback we've received, we were recommended deploying upgrades to existing implementation contracts via OpenZeppelin's TUP.
Would this be the correct approach to upgrading one of our contracts in the future using foundry?
Would we only need to point to the proxy address since the proxy will be able to point to the correct implementation address every upgrade?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol";
import "forge-std/Script.sol";
import "src/ExampleV1.sol";

contract DeployExample is Script {
    function run() external {
        // Fetch the private key as a string and parse it as uint256
        string memory privateKeyStr = vm.envString("PRIVATE_KEY");
        uint256 deployerPrivateKey = vm.parseUint(privateKeyStr);
        address exampleV0ImplementationAddress = vm.envAddress("EXAMPLE_V0_ADDRESS");
        address exampleProxyAddress = vm.envAddress("EXAMPLE_PROXY_ADDRESS");

        vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);
      
        console.log("EXAMPLE V0 contract deployed at:", exampleV0ImplementationAddress);
        console.log("EXAMPLE PROXY contract deployed at:", exampleProxyAddress);

         // Optionally, upgrade the proxy to point to the new implementation
        ExampleV1 newImplementation = new ExampleV1();
        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature("initialize()");
        ITransparentUpgradeableProxy(payable(exampleProxyAddress)).upgradeToAndCall(address(newImplementation), data);

        console.log("EXAMPLE proxy upgraded to new implementation (V1) at:", address(newImplementation));

        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}

